# How to sort json specific key value in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to sort this json by 'Count' key values:

```
{
  "17-April": {
    "https://www.dom1.com/": [
      {
        "Cant": 5
      },
      {
        "Links": [
          "https://www.dom1.com/1",
          "https://www.dom1.com/2",
          "https://www.dom1.com/3",
          "https://www.dom1.com/4",
          "https://www.dom1.com/5"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "https://www.dom2.com/": [
      {
        "Cant": 3
      },
      {
        "Links": [
          "https://www.dom2.com/",
          "https://www.dom2.com/",
          "https://www.dom2.com/"
    ],
    "https://www.dom3.com/": [
      {
        "Cant": 4
      },
      {
        "Links": [
          "https://www.dom3.com/1",
          "https://www.dom3.com/2",
          "https://www.dom3.com/3",
          "https://wwwdom3.com/4"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "19-April": {
    "https://www.dom1.com/": [
      {
        "Cant": 7
      },
      {
        "Links": [
          "https://www.dom1.com/1",
          "https://www.dom1.com/2",
          "https://www.dom1.com/3",
          "https://www.dom1.com/4",
          "https://www.dom1.com/5",
          "https://www.dom1.com/6",
          "https://www.dom1.com/7"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "https://www.dom2.com/": [
      {
        "Cant": 2
      },
      {
        "Links": [
          "https://www.dom2.com/",
          "https://www.dom2.com/"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "https://www.dom3.com/": [
      {
        "Cant": 8
      },
      {
        "Links": [
          "https://www.dom3.com/1",
          "https://www.dom3.com/2",
          "https://www.dom3.com/3",
          "https://www.dom3.com/4",
          "https://www.dom3.com/5",
          "https://www.dom3.com/6",
          "https://www.dom3.com/7",
          "https://www.dom3.com/7"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
```

This json gets repeated by date, I would like to sort it by the values of the "Count" key.

This json takes several domains by date, thats why I want to sorted by count, To have it nicely sorted by domain wit more links every day

The ideal sorting it would be: by date -> count

Comment: When you say `This json gets repeated by date` what do you mean. Is there a list holding this that you didn't show? You've only shown one dictionary. It doesn't make sense to sort that.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry if I didn't put many details. I have a script that I execute every day and opens this json file and adds the same structured data only changing date key and key values of count and links.

Comment: Does `domain` have multiple entries?

Comment: This json takes several domains by date, thats why I want to sorted by count, To have it nicely sorted by domain wit more links every day

Comment: @JamesPowis Yes

Comment: Sorry if I don't provide a detailed description, I'm new on this so I'm still learning a lot

Comment: so you want to sort the entries specifically in Domains? or do you want to also sort Dates?

Comment: @451mm you can still edit the question. It would be helpful to add more than one object, and the expected output.

Comment: @JamesPowis The ideal sorting it would be: by date -> count

Comment: @MarkMeyer Done editing

Comment: I can even modify the json structured if need it.

Comment: I just updated my answer, it sorts by date, but your date value is largely not sortable in its current state. It would take a lot of logic to consume that as a datetime object and then sort off of it. It would be better to fix how your storing the data in the first place.

Comment: ur json data is not right; i'm getting EOF parsing, possibly due to a missing bracket or brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the data is in rough shape... It is a dictionary with dates in a non-sortable format, I would recommend YYYY-MM-DD so that it sorts cleanly. The values of the dates are dictionaries with anonymous keys whos value is an array dissimilar items.

I would highly recommend storing the data like the output of this:
`[{"date":"YYYY-MM-DD", "domains": [{"domain": "string:", "count": 1, "links": ["link1"]}]}]`

If you cannot do that, then this chunk will migrate your example into that structure:

```py
cleaned_data = []
for date, v in data.items():
    o = {
        'date': date,
        'domains': []
    }
    for domain, dv in v.items():
        o['domains'].append({
            'domain': domain,
            'count': dv[0]['Cant'],
            'links': dv[1]['Links']
        })
    cleaned_data.append(o)
```

And this chunk will sort it as desired. (note I am not playing with datetime conversions... I don't consider that inscope for this question.)

```py
for v in cleaned_data:
    v['domains'] = sorted(v['domains'], key = lambda i: i['count'])

sorted_data = sorted(cleaned_data, key = lambda i: i['date'])
print(sorted_data)
```

Comment: If you look at the edit, you'll see that "Domain" isn't actually a key (unfortunately).

Comment: You get a vote from me for working through that json format! Nice suggestion for new data format too.

Comment: @JamesPowis Thank you so much! It worked. I changed the json structured and worked perfectly.